# How to create a fresh Shelve Changelist in Perforce

Tags: perforce, unshelve

I made some changes in few files (lets say F1, F2, F3) in workspace A. I shelved these changes (shelved ID#1) (no issues so far) and unshelved these changes to new workspace B (No issues). After unshelving in B, I made few more changes in files (F2, F3, F4 and F5) in workspace B. Now I want to move changes from workspace B to a new workspace C. Here I am facing problem.

1. When I tried Shelving from workspace B, it listed only files F4 and F5 in shelved list (Shelved Id#2), instead of all modifiled files (F1, F2, F3, F4 and F5). When I do $P4 opened ..., it lists all 5 modified files, However, shelved CL takes only the files which are modified in the exclusively workspace B.
2. I tried unshelving both the IDs 1 & 2). However, I did not get the changes made in workspace B in files F2 and F3.

How can I make my all changes (all 5 files) from workspace B to workspace C.
More specifically, how I can I create fresh Shelve from workspace B which contains all the changes, not just the changes made post unshelving.

Hope somebody can help me with this quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take all the files you currently have open in workspace B, and make a fresh shelf with all those changes, do:

```
p4 reopen -c default //...
p4 shelve
```

The first command takes all your opened files, and associates them with the default changelist.

The second command takes all files currently opened in the default changelist, and makes a new shelf with those changes.